# Basemap interpolation alternative - regridding data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, interpolation, matplotlib-basemap

I'm moving from basemap to cartopy given basemap is going to be phased out. I've previously used the basemap.interp functionality to interpolate data, e.g. say I have data at 1 degree resolution (180x360), I would run the following to interpolate to 0.5 degrees.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits import basemap

Old_Lon = np.linspace(-180,180,360)
Old_Lat = np.linspace(-90,90,180)
New_Lon = np.linspace(-180,180,720)
New_Lat = np.linspace(-90,90,360)

New_Lon,New_Lat = np.meshgrid(New_Lon,New_Lat)

New_Data = basemap.interp(Old_Data,Old_Lon,Old_Lat,New_Lon,New_Lat,order=0)
```

`order` gives me options to choose from nearest neighbour, bi-linear etc. Is there an alternative that does this in as simple way? I've seen scipy has interpolation but I'm not sure how to apply it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually decided to take the raw code from Basemap and make it into a standalone function  - I'll be recommending it to the cartopy guys to implement it as its a useful feature. Posting here as could be useful to someone else:

```
def Interp(datain,xin,yin,xout,yout,interpolation='NearestNeighbour'):

    """
       Interpolates a 2D array onto a new grid (only works for linear grids), 
       with the Lat/Lon inputs of the old and new grid. Can perfom nearest
       neighbour interpolation or bilinear interpolation (of order 1)'

       This is an extract from the basemap module (truncated)
    """

    # Mesh Coordinates so that they are both 2D arrays
    xout,yout = np.meshgrid(xout,yout)

   # compute grid coordinates of output grid.
    delx = xin[1:]-xin[0:-1]
    dely = yin[1:]-yin[0:-1]

    xcoords = (len(xin)-1)*(xout-xin[0])/(xin[-1]-xin[0])
    ycoords = (len(yin)-1)*(yout-yin[0])/(yin[-1]-yin[0])


    xcoords = np.clip(xcoords,0,len(xin)-1)
    ycoords = np.clip(ycoords,0,len(yin)-1)

    # Interpolate to output grid using nearest neighbour
    if interpolation == 'NearestNeighbour':
        xcoordsi = np.around(xcoords).astype(np.int32)
        ycoordsi = np.around(ycoords).astype(np.int32)
        dataout = datain[ycoordsi,xcoordsi]

    # Interpolate to output grid using bilinear interpolation.
    elif interpolation == 'Bilinear':
        xi = xcoords.astype(np.int32)
        yi = ycoords.astype(np.int32)
        xip1 = xi+1
        yip1 = yi+1
        xip1 = np.clip(xip1,0,len(xin)-1)
        yip1 = np.clip(yip1,0,len(yin)-1)
        delx = xcoords-xi.astype(np.float32)
        dely = ycoords-yi.astype(np.float32)
        dataout = (1.-delx)*(1.-dely)*datain[yi,xi] + \
                  delx*dely*datain[yip1,xip1] + \
                  (1.-delx)*dely*datain[yip1,xi] + \
                  delx*(1.-dely)*datain[yi,xip1]

    return dataout
```

--

Answer (score 3):

The SciPy interpolation routines return a function that you can call to perform an interpolation. For nearest neighbour interpolation on a regular grid, you can use `scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

nearest_function = RegularGridInterpolator(
    (old_lon, old_lat), old_data, method="nearest", bounds_error=False
)

new_data = np.array(
    [[nearest_function([i, j]) for j in new_lat] for i in new_lon]
).squeeze()
```

That isn't perfect, though, because `lon=175` are all fill values. (If I hadn't set `bounds_error=False` then you'd get an error there.) In that case, you need to ask how you want to wrap around the dateline. A straightforward solution would be to copy the `lon=0` line to the end of the array and call it `lon=180`.

Should you want linear or higher order interpolation one day, which I'd recommend if your data are points rather than cells, you can use `scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

old_step = 10
old_lon = np.arange(-180, 180, old_step)
old_lat = np.arange(-90, 90, old_step)
old_data = np.random.random((len(old_lon), len(old_lat)))
interp_function = RectBivariateSpline(old_lon, old_lat, old_data, kx=1, ky=1)

new_lon = np.arange(-180, 180, new_step)
new_lat = np.arange(-90, 90, new_step)
new_data = interp_function(new_lon, new_lat)
```

Comment: This is a really good answer, thank you. My only concern with the nearest neighbour is the length of time it takes to run vs basemap.interp function.

Comment: I made a work around by copying the basemap.interp function from the source code and making it into a standalone function. Thanks!

Comment: I'd expect the map creation to take longer than the interpolation in most cases, but I never got around to learning Basemap. Also, if you think it's that useful, you could ask Cartopy to make a copy of this routine. Mark's fairly friendly :)

Answer (score 0):

`cartopy` has this function called `cartopy.img_transform.im_trans.regrid` now.

E.g.,

```
import numpy as np
from cartopy.img_transform import regrid
from cartopy import crs as ccrs
    
Old_Lon = np.linspace(-180,180,360)
Old_Lat = np.linspace(-90,90,180)
New_Lon = np.linspace(-180,180,720)
New_Lat = np.linspace(-90,90,360)

New_Lon,New_Lat = np.meshgrid(New_Lon,New_Lat)

source_cs = ccrs.PlateCarree()
target_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

New_Data = regrid(Old_Data,Old_Lon,Old_Lat, source_cs, target_proj, New_Lon,New_Lat)
```